# How to instantiate record from generic package

Tags: ada

I am new to Ada and am having some issues. I have created a generic Date package:

Date.ads:

```
GENERIC

PACKAGE Date IS
  TYPE MonthName IS (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August,
   September, October, November, December);

  TYPE DateRec IS RECORD
    Month: MonthName;
    Day: Integer RANGE 1..31;
    Year: Integer;
  END RECORD;

  PROCEDURE PrintDate(Adate: IN DateRec);
END Date;
```

Date.adb:

```
WITH Ada.Text_IO;
USE Ada.Text_IO;

PACKAGE BODY Date  IS

PACKAGE MonthNameIO IS NEW Ada.Text_IO.Enumeration_IO(MonthName);
USE MonthNameIO;

PACKAGE IntegerIO IS NEW Ada.Text_IO.Enumeration_IO(Integer);
USE IntegerIO;

PROCEDURE PrintDate(Adate: IN DateRec) IS
  BEGIN
    Put(Adate.Month);
    Put(Adate.Day,3);
    Put(",");
    Put(Adate.Year, 5);
    New_Line;
  END PrintDate;
END Date;
```

I want to be able to use "DateRec" in a program, but encounter errors when I attempt to compile.  The calling code:

```
WITH Date;
...
PACKAGE Date_Stack IS NEW Gstack(StackSize, DateRec);
```

I get the following errors when I compile:

```
genstack.adb:176:57: "DateRec" is not visible (more references follow)
genstack.adb:176:57: non-visible declaration at date.ads:7
```

What am I missing?

Ok, now the problem I am having is when I attempt to use an object:

```
TempDate: Date.DateRec;
...
Get(TempDate.Month);
```

The compile now gives me:

```
genstack.adb:201:25: missing argument for parameter "Item" in call to "Get" declared at a-tienio.ads:65, instance at line 183
```

Comment: The language is "Ada", not "ADA" (it's a name, not an acronym).

Comment: Your indentation in `Date.adb` is off; everything from `Package MonthNameIO ...` to `PROCEDURE PrintDate` should be indented one more level. Also, the usual modern convention for Ada code is to put keywords in lowercase, not all-caps (that's the convention used in the Ada Reference Manual).

Comment: With regard to your edit: you should really ask a new question. As it is, I suspect that there’s no equivalent of `MonthNameIO` visible at the point where the error occurs; you’ve done the instantiation in the body of Date. Perhaps you could move it to the visible part of the spec.

Comment: As @SimonWright says, that's a new question, unrelated to the original one. Does line 183 refer to your declaration of `MonthNameIO`? That call `Get(TempDate.Month);` looks correct. If you want help, narrow down your code to a simple example that demonstrates that problem (*not* the original one) and post it in a new question.

Comment: I think Simon nailed this one.  `MonthNameIO.Get` is visible only within the body of `Date`, not outside it, since it's declared in the body of `Date`.  The reason for the confusing error message is probably that there's some other `Get`[s] visible, probably from another instance of `Enumeration_IO`, and the compiler is trying to make your call fit into the declaration of those other `Get`[s].

Comment: By the way, don't instantiate `Enumeration_IO(Integer)`; use `Integer_IO(Integer)` instead.  Using `Enumeration_IO(Integer)` is apparently legal, but the effect is totally undefined (A.10.10(17)), and it could just do something weird when you try to run it.  Even better, don't write your own instantiation at all, but use `Ada.Integer_Text_IO` since the language provides it for your convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Date` package has no generic parameters, so there's probably no point in making it generic.

If you drop the `GENERIC` keyword, it will likely work (I haven't actually tried it myself).

If you really do want it to be generic, then you'll need to *instantiate* it before you can use it. `Date` is not a package; it's a generic package.

```
 generic
 package Date is
 ...
 end Date;

 package MyDate is new Date;
```

Now `MyDate` is a (non-generic) package, and you can refer to `MyDate.DateRec`.

By making it generic with no generic parameters, you can create multiple instantiations, each of which is a distinct package, so that `MyDate.DateRec` and `YourDate.DateRec` are distinct types. It's not clear that that's worthwhile.

Normally a generic package has one or more parameters, so that different instances operate on different types. You even have examples of that in your code: `Ada.Text_IO.Enumeration_IO` is generic, and your `MonthNameIO` is a specific instance of that generic package.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my first issue.  Now I have a new one dealing with Get().  I have updated the original post with more details.